# How to do a simple merge?

Tags: git, merge

I want to get file_3 by merging file_1 and file_2

If manual merge needed, text editor or merge tools can be used, preferably file_3 is in git merge like format.

file_1 is in git, but both with or without git to do the merge is fine

I am on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 3-way merging git uses you need **THREE** versions of the file: "ours" version, "theirs" version, i.e. versions you want to merge, but you also need "common" version, i.e. version of file that was common source for "ours" and "theirs" version; for Git it would be version from merge base of current branch and the branch you are merging.

The algorithm and the way to mark merge conflicts Git uses is nearly the same as the one used by `rcsmerge` tool from RCS (long time ago Git required rcsmerge installed), and by `diff3 -E`.  You can run it by hand using low level (plumbing) command [`git merge-file`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `git`, you could:

(Let's assume that the `master` branch contains the `file1`)

- create a new branch, `git co -b 0001-merging-one-file`
- overwrite `file1` in this branch with `file2`, via editor or by any other means ..
- checkout master again, `git co master`
- merge your 'temporary branch' into master, `git pull . 0001-merging-one-file`
- no step 5 ;)

Comment: is it possible to pull from master to temp branch. since this is temporary merge, don't want to affect master...

Comment: yes, it should be possible .. the procedure would stay similar

Comment: it tells already up-to-date. file 2 should not be committed to temp branch?

Answer (score -3):

```
cat file1 file2 > merged_file
```

Comment: this is just CATenate 2 files not merge.

what I mean is merge 2 versions of the same file. like git merge on branches.